# Can Firefox use an SVG for a background

Tags: firefox, svg, firefox3.5

Can Firefox 3.5 use an SVG for a background image?

Comment: Have you given it a try to find out?

Comment: Yes - I tried it and I was having difficulty.  That is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't.

I tried it.

If you want to try it, you can find an SVG image [here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c7/SVG.svg).

Answer (score 5):

I'm actually currently working on supporting this in Firefox.  It doesn't work yet, but it probably will in the next release (version 4.0).

The bug page is here, if you want to follow progress:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276431